# Is there a way to have an array of uninitialized classes that aren't destructed when delete[] is called?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor, delete-operator, type-erasure

I'm implementing an object pool with type erasure so that pools can be stored in collections and can store other pools. The functionality is in place, but also features a memory leak coming from not deleting the pool itself. I have the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ObjectPool::PoolModel final : PoolConcept {
    PoolModel(uint size) : pool( new T[size](), [](T _[]){ /*Problem!*/}) {}
    virtual ~PoolModel() {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[], std::function<void(T[])>> pool;
};
```

Fittingly, "Problem!" is where my problem is. You may wonder why I've substituted uinique_ptr's default delete for one that does nothing. This is because the pool is filled with completely bogus data at destruction time and so when a pool of pools is destroyed (or any pool of objects carrying smart pointer's or other objects with destructors) then the array delete will call the destructor of each class and follow up by deleting a bogus smart pointer which causes a segfault. So I substituted the noop destructor and everything functions peachy.

Hence the memory leak. I've gotten rid of the default delete and so each pool object leaves behind it's pool. I have tried "::operator delete[](arr);" in the "Problem!" spot, since it supposedly deletes an array without calling the object's destructors, but that yields "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer." I'm trying to find a c++ way to do this and not need to resort to malloc and free. Furthermore I'd like to know if there's a way to allocate the array in the first place without calling a default constructor for each array member and just leave them uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of `T`s must always be filled with valid `T` objects.  There are no exceptions.

The solution to your problems is to not use an array of `T` objects.  Instead, allocate uninitialized storage with the proper size and alignment for n `T` objects and initialize them with placement-new.  You will then be responsible for manually calling the `T` objects' destructors.  This is the solution `std::vector` and similar data structures use:

```
template <typename T>
struct ObjectPool::PoolModel final : PoolConcept {
    using StorageT = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
    PoolModel(uint capacity)
       : pool{ std::make_unique<StorageT[]>(capacity) },
         size{0},
         capacity{capacity}
    {}

    virtual ~PoolModel() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            T* ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&pool[i]));
            ptr->~T();
        }
    }

    void insert(T obj) {
        assert(capacity > size);
        new (&pool[size + 1]) T{std::move(obj)};
        ++size;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<StorageT[]> pool;
    uint size;
    uint capacity;
};
```

---

Of course, since you're basically re-inventing a `std::vector`, you could just use `std::vector` instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct ObjectPool::PoolModel final : PoolConcept {
    PoolModel(uint capacity) {
        pool.reserve(capacity);
    }

    virtual ~PoolModel() {}

    void insert(T obj) {
        pool.push_back(std::move(obj));
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> pool;
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen use of aligned_storage_t before. Thanks, that looks like it'll work. I can't, however, use a vector because the pool needs to be able to delete and replace at random indices as quick as possible. Remove, push_back, insert, etc. are all pretty slow for my use case and order/resize-ability doesn't matter.

Comment: @GarinStrader Generally the idea of an object pool is to not create and delete objects at all.  Your objects live for the entire lifetime of the pool and you just mark them active or inactive and modify their state as needed.

Comment: That's very true. I wont go into why exactly, but I'll actually be using multiple different implementations including what you describe. This one may or may not end up going in the trash depending on how fast it is and other factors but it's at least a fun exercise